# about the Beurling Theorem in Murphy's book

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Here is a part of Murphy's book C*-Algebras and Operator Theory:
[image]

In the fourth line of his proof, he claims that $1-\lambda a$ is invertible. But we do not have  $||\lambda a|| <1$, how to show invertibility of $1-\lambda a$? Thanks!

Comment: $\Delta$ is the open disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\lambda^{-1} -a$ invertible because $|\lambda^{-1}|>r(a)$ (since $|\lambda|<1/r(a)$). Then
$$
1-\lambda a=\lambda\,(\lambda^{-1}-a)
$$
is invertible. The case $\lambda=0$ is trivial.